# Authorize&Capture New Order total

Tags: invoice, authorize.net, authorize

We are using authorize.net payment method with payment action as authorize. We also have an order edit module where we can update the order totals.So when the order total is updated and then if we are trying to create the invoice to capture the latest amount,we are getting the issue like "Transaction has been declined. Please try again later.".

So we need to void the existing transcation,authorize it and then capture.I was able to void the transcation but unable to find how to authorize and capture the new order total.

Can anyone please guide me on how to achieve this

Thanks!

Comment: I am calling the authorize function on the order payment object but i am receiving error like "Opaque data does not exist"

Comment: im also getting same error. You got solution?

Comment: Yes we have used direct Authorize.net API calls